# Padrão de projetos para combinar dados vindo de Bancos de Dados diferentes

Tags: c#, json, banco-de-dados, design-pattern

Estou pegando dados de dois bancos de dados diferentes e preciso formatar esses dados para Json.

O problema não é acessar os dois bancos e pegar as informações. O problema é que a minha classe ficou mais complexa do que deveria. Um dos campos do meu Json é dependente de dados que estão em outro banco. Então, para cada vez que construo o Json com dados de um banco, preciso ir em outro banco para preencher essas informação. Segue um exemplo de código:

```
public class JsonClipAlerta
    {
        public JsonClipAlerta()
        {
        }

        public long Id;
        public IList<string> EnderecosEletronicos { get; set; }
        public IList<ExpressoesStruct> Expressoes { get; set; }
        public string IdCript { get; set; }

        public static JsonClipAlerta FromClipAlerta(ClipAlerta arg, Usuario usuarioLogado)
        {
            var crypto = ContainerHelper.Resolve<IServicoDeCriptografia>();
            var jsonClipAlerta = new JsonClipAlerta();
            var repositorioEnderecoEletronico = ContainerHelper.Resolve<ComuniqueSeWorkflow.Dominio.IRepositorios.IRepositorioEnderecoEletronico>();

            jsonClipAlerta.Id = arg.Id; 
            jsonClipAlerta.IdCript = crypto.Criptografar(arg.Id);
            jsonClipAlerta.Expressoes = arg.Expressoes.Select(e => new ExpressoesStruct { id = crypto.Criptografar(e.Id), text = e.Descricao }).ToList();
            jsonClipAlerta.EnderecosEletronicos = repositorioEnderecoEletronico.RetornaColecao (arg.EnderecosEletronicos.ToList()).Select(ee => ee.Endereco).ToList();

            return jsonClipAlerta;
        }        
    }

    public struct ExpressoesStruct {
        public string id;
        public string text;
    }
```

Comment: Mas se você tem dois bancos sempre vai ter q ir no outro pra obter o restante da informação, qual o problema? Poste a classe também, pois o seu código só tem a parte final, você se refere ao filtro usando lambda?

Comment: @Laerte isso está fazendo com que a classe fique muito complexa. Gostaria de saber se há algum design pattern pra me auxiliar isso. Havia imaginado uma classe simples que faria só um parse de tudo já pronto e formataria pro Json.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se entendi o cenário. Você está dizendo que para obter o seu objeto "JsonClipAlerta" devidamente preenchido, precisa fazer uma busca em uma base que veio do parâmetro de "ClipAlerta" e depois fazer a chamada para repositorioEnderecoEletronico.RetornaColecao() com uma informação dele? Se for isso, de onde vem ClipAlerta e quem preencheu ele?

Comment: @DiegoJeronymo, o ClipAlerta vem do banco. Quando eu chamo JsonClipAlerta.FromClipAlerta(ClipAlerta), eu já passo o ClipAlerta preenchido faltando apenas o campo EnderecosEletronicos. Estou pensando em fazer um Builder para montar o ClipAlerta. O que acha?

Comment: @tiagopotencia não consigo dizer nesse caso se vale a pena, porque não está claro no caso do ClipAlerta como ele é criado ou qual a responsabilidade dele no seu contexto. Ele serve como uma classe para guardar os dados da sua primeira consulta ou ele é uma entidade mais complexa? O Builder, por ser um pattern criacional, depende de quem deve saber como construí-lo e se ele pode ser construído através de diferentes combinações (seja por diferentes parâmetros ou ações que desencadeiam diferentes características), e é preciso entender melhor o cenário para dizer se ele é ou não uma boa escolha.

Comment: Recomendo que na pergunta você especifique melhor o contexto das suas classes JsonClipAlerta e ClipAlerta, além de indicar quem tem a responsabilidade de chamá-los, quem conhece/depende de quem e qual o resultado esperado. Não consigo te recomendar nenhuma técnica específica ou design pattern sem entender com clareza qual o fluxo que você está tentando representar com o seu código.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Answer (score 1):

Existem várias abordagens para resolver esse problema, uma delas é usando os princípios de [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) junto com [Software Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern).

Podemos começar pelo princípio de "Single Responsability" (o "S" do SOLID) ou responsabilidade única e perguntar: "de quem é a responsabilidade de criar um JsonClipAlerta?" Talvez uma fábrica de objetos seja mais adequada para essa tarefa. "Quantas fábricas vão existir no programa?" Provavelmente apenas uma. "Essa fábrica vai ter quais '*fornecedores*' de informações?" Talvez possamos  contratatar (ou "injetar") os fornecedores através de um contrato (ou "interface").

Logo podemos usar uma combinação de *patterns*: vamos então criar uma fábrica de objetos de instancia única que vai receber via injeção de dependências os dois provedores de informações, vamos combinar um [Singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) com [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) mais [Dependency Injection Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx) para termos alta coesão, ou seja, cada classe com uma responsabilidade e termos baixo acomplamento, quer dizer, cada classe não depender de outra classe, a não ser de interfaces, que é o príncipio "D" (Dependency inversion principle) do SOLID que diz que devemos depender de abstrações (interfaces) ao invés de implementações (classes).

O nosso objetivo é que possamos criar o *Json* da seguinte forma:

```
JsonClipAlerta json = JsonClipAlertaFactory.Instance
.CreateJsonClipAlerta(new JsonClipArguments { Id = 100, InitialDate = DateTime.Now });
```

Assim uma possível solução de fábrica seria:

```
    public sealed class JsonClipAlertaFactory
    {
          // providers que serão inicializados no construtor
          private readonly IProviderClipAlerta providerClip;
          private readonly IRepositorioEnderecoEletronico providerEndereco;

          // Factory method que cria os objetos
          public JsonClipAlerta CreateJsonClipAlerta(JsonClipArguments args)
          {
             ClipAlerta clip = this.providerClip.GetClipAlerta(args.Id);

             var jsonClip = new JsonClipAlerta()
             {
                // Informações vindas do primeiro provider
                Id = clip.Id,
                Expressoes = clip.Expressoes,

                // Informações vindas do segundo provider 
                EnderecosEletronicos = this.providerEndereco
                .RetornaColecao(clip.EnderecosEletronicos.ToList())
             };

             return jsonClip;
          }

          // Singleton com construtor privado que recebe os providers
          private JsonClipAlertaFactory(
             IProviderClipAlerta providerClip,
             IRepositorioEnderecoEletronico providerEndereco)
          {
             this.providerClip = providerClip;
             this.providerEndereco = providerEndereco;
          }

          public static JsonClipAlertaFactory Instance 
          { 
              get { return Nested.instance; } 
          }

          private class Nested
          {
             // Construtor estático para dizer ao compilador C# 
             // não marcar tipo como 'beforefieldinit'
             static Nested() { }

             // Passando os providers para o construtor privado
             internal static readonly JsonClipAlertaFactory instance =
                new JsonClipAlertaFactory(
                    new ProviderClipAlerta(), 
                    new RepositorioEnderecoEletronico());
          }
       }
```

Com as seguintes classes, de ilustração para o nosso exemplo de factory acima:

```
  // Classes de 'ilustração' usada na nossa Factory acima
 public class ClipAlerta
   {
      public long Id { get; set; }
      public IList<ExpressoesStruct> Expressoes { get; set; }
      public IList<string> EnderecosEletronicos { get; set; }
   }

   // Interfaces e classes dos providers   
   public interface IProviderClipAlerta
   {
      ClipAlerta GetClipAlerta(long id);
   }

   public interface IRepositorioEnderecoEletronico
   {
      IList<string> RetornaColecao(IList<string> listaEmails);
   }

   public class ProviderClipAlerta : IProviderClipAlerta
   {
      public ClipAlerta GetClipAlerta(long id)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }

   public class RepositorioEnderecoEletronico : IRepositorioEnderecoEletronico
   {
      public IList<string> RetornaColecao(IList<string> listaEmails)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }

   // Struct para auxiliar a passagem de parametros
   public struct JsonClipArguments
   {
      public long Id;
      public DateTime InitialDate;      
      // outros parametros..
   }
```